# Best way to avoid duplicate long text entries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, webforms, unique-key

I have a requirement to gather a form input and store it into the database. That is pretty easy.  The difficult part is that I can not make a unique key on a long text field.

In this kind of a situation, what is usually done to help prevent duplicate entries from being entered by users?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? This is a very odd request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED**

**Direct Question:**

You should create an additional field as in this eaxmple

```
myId int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
myText TEXT,
myUnique VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
UNIQUE KEY myUnique (myUnique)

<form>
<textarea name="myText" ></textarea>
<input type="hidden" value="UNIQUE-ID" name="myUnique" />
</form>
```

**NOTE:**

> - a ***`UNIQUE-ID`*** can be generated in php in many ways something built-in function are [MD5](http://php.net/manual/en/function.md5.php) - [SHA1](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php) - [RAND](http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php) - [UNIQUEID](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php) - [TIME](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) - [CRC32](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crc32.php)

**EXAMPLE:**

```
$myUnique = crc32("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.");
```

**Further SO Readings:**

> - [Unique text field in MySQL and php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2594328/unique-text-field-in-mysql-and-php)
> - [What is the best way to check for duplicate TEXT fields in MYSQL/PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902478/what-is-the-best-way-to-check-for-duplicate-text-fields-in-mysql-php)

Comment: Yes, I am aware that there is documentation out there.  But I asked a direct question.

Comment: humm, infact a direct question is in theese two 3d.

Answer (score 3):

Create a separate `MD5` hash of the `LONGTEXT` entry to be triggered on `INSERT` and `UPDATE`. That hash column should have a `UNIQUE` key and should be of `CHAR` type (since it will always be the same size). This will allow for the unique key.

Comment: Sorry, I totally don't understand what you mean.  What is an md5 hash? How do I make it triggered on insert/update? How would it work with the char column?  Very cryptic answer.

Answer (score 1):

Create an index on your long text field.  Then before saving a record, search the exisitng records for the test the user just entered. If found, don't allow the save.

Comment: Isn't it very bad for performance to create an index on a long text entry?

Comment: The index will greatly improve the speed for searching duplicates.  It certainly will be much faster than a full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $text='the long text to be inserted the long text to be inserted the long text to be inserted the long text to be inserted';
 //assuming field name (mylongtextfield)
 $result=mysql_query("SELECT id FROM mytable WHERE md5(mylongtextfield)='".md5($text)."'";
 if(!$result){
      //do your insert query
 }else{
      echo "the text already exist!";   
 }
```